# React-material table how to get editable rendered component

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have specified column of `react-material-table` this way:

```
 {
    accessorKey: 'gender',
    header: 'Gender',
    muiTableBodyCellEditTextFieldProps: ({ cell }) => ({
      select: true,
      children: [GENDER.ALL, GENDER.MALE, GENDER.FEMALE].map(e => (<MenuItem key={e} value={e}>
        {e}
      </MenuItem>))
    }),
  },
```

How do I get the element rendered by `react-material-table` on each row?

Comment: Do you mean the menu item? What is your use case for needing the element reference?